# Sigma.js in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, sigma.js

I am having trouble using Sigma.js inside an Angular directive.

The steps I am taking are:

1. I have built my app with yeoman.
2. I have installed sigma as a bower_component and did run `npm run build` to obtained the minified `sigma.min.js`
3. I have added it as a script in my `index.html`
4. I have added `sigma` as a dependency in my `app.js`.
5. I have imported it as a dependency in my directive as `sigma`

The error that I am getting is: `module 'sigma' is not available`

Does anybody have an idea on what's going on?

This is the code:
app.js

```
angular.module('uiApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'd3',
  'directives',
  'services',
  'sigma'
])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

sigmagraph.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('directives')
.directive('sigmagraph',['$log','sigma',function($log,sigma){

    return {

        scope:true,
        restrict:'EA',
        link: function (scope,el){

            sigma.parsers.json('data.json', {
                container: 'container',
                settings: {
                    defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148'
                }
            });


        }


    };


}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Beware:** *although this should work, it is a very slow implementation (see comments)*

For future reference, I made a simple Sigma.Js (v.1.0.3) Directive for AngularJs (1.2.25). It can be found in this gist: [Simple Sigma.Js AngularJs Directive](https://gist.github.com/patrickfav/cd20939b383b9c284511)

It features only the basics (graph, width, height) but can easily be extended to your needs.

Here is the naked directive. See gist for full example.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('sigmajs-ng', []).directive('sigmajs', function() {
        //over-engineered random id, so that multiple instances can be put on a single page
        var divId = 'sigmjs-dir-container-'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999999999))+'-'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999999999))+'-'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999999999));
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div id="'+divId+'" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;"></div>',
            scope: {
                //@ reads the attribute value, = provides two-way binding, & works with functions
                graph: '=',
                width: '@',
                height: '@',
                releativeSizeNode: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                // Let's first initialize sigma:
                var s = new sigma({
                    container: divId,
                    settings: {
                        defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148',
                        labelThreshold: 4
                    }
                });


                scope.$watch('graph', function(newVal,oldVal) {
                    s.graph.clear();
                    s.graph.read(scope.graph);
                    s.refresh();
                    if(scope.releativeSizeNode) {
                        //this feature needs the plugin to be added
                        sigma.plugins.relativeSize(s, 2);
                    }
                });

                scope.$watch('width', function(newVal,oldVal) {
                    console.log("graph width: "+scope.width);
                    element.children().css("width",scope.width);
                    s.refresh();
                    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')); //hack so that it will be shown instantly
                });
                scope.$watch('height', function(newVal,oldVal) {
                    console.log("graph height: "+scope.height);
                    element.children().css("height",scope.height);
                    s.refresh();
                    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));//hack so that it will be shown instantly
                });

                element.on('$destroy', function() {
                    s.graph.clear();
                });
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

Comment: scope.$watch('graph') will kill performances because the graph object will be hashed each time the $digest cycle is triggered, which may be several times per second. Never, ever do this.

Comment: Please don't ever `scope.$watch('graph', fn)`. Ever. It'll digest  all graph objects over and over and kill your performances.

Answer (score 3):

I'm writing a guide to integrate Sigma and its plugins into Angular, see https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/wiki/How-to-integrate-with-Angular.js

This approach has been successfully implemented in Linkurious Enterprise and works with thousands of nodes and edges.

Answer (score 2):

Sigma.js is not an angular module, so you cannot require it. It's a standlone Javascript library. If you just want to use Sigma.js in a directive, you only have to add it to your index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bower install sigma.js
```

But look here before: https://github.com/tuvistavie/sigma-bower